# Concatenate a column from multiple rows into a single formatted string

Tags: postgresql

I have rows like so:

```
roll_no
---------
0690543
0005331
0760745
0005271
```

And I want string like this :

```
"0690543.pdf" "0005331.pdf" "0760745.pdf" "0005271.pdf"
```

I have tried concat but unable to do so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an aggregate function like [`string_agg`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES), after first mangling the quotes and the .pdf extension to your column data. Use a space as your delimiter:

```
SELECT string_agg('"'||roll_no||'.pdf "', ' ') from myTable
```

[SqlFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/93cdb/6)